# How to configure/setup Paypal Venmo in Magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, paypal, magento2.4.6

I was wondering how to enable the Venmo payment method through PayPal on Magento 2. I checked the PayPal Express/Standard and Advanced Payment methods, but I couldn't find any information about enabling Venmo. Any help?